# Validation fails for the XML against its own schema generated in Visual Studio

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xsd, xmlhttprequest, xsd-validation

I have one XML which I am planning to send out after validating against its schema. I generated the schema for this XML in Visual Studio and it gives 3 different XSDs as the XML contains 3 different namespaces. But when I am validating the same XML instance against the main schema, it fails at one record type.

I have tried manipulating the XML, but that disrupts my http request which I am planning to send out. Also tried multiple solutions on SOF but nothing helped so far.

My XML looks like this-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<updateList xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:messages_namespace" xmlns:listRel="urn:relationships_namespace" xmlns:pc="urn:core_namespace">
  <pc:record xsi:type="listRel:Customer" internalId="46" xmlns:listRel="urn:relationships_namespace">
    <listRel:companyName>T Tax</listRel:companyName>
  </pc:record>
  <pc:record xsi:type="listRel:Customer" internalId="44" xmlns:listRel="urn:relationships_namespace">
    <listRel:companyName>S Tax</listRel:companyName>
  </pc:record>
  <pc:record xsi:type="listRel:Customer" internalId="45" xmlns:listRel="urn:relationships_namespace">
    <listRel:companyName>K Tax</listRel:companyName>
  </pc:record>
</updateList>
```

Main schema that got generated looks like this-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:pc="urn:core_namespace" xmlns:listRel="urn:relationships_namespace" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:messages_namespace">
  <xsd:import namespace="urn:core_namespace" schemaLocation="UpdateCustomer1.xsd"/>
  <xsd:element name="updateList">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="pc:record" />
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The schema file alone is getting validated in Visual Studio, but when I am giving the same XML as input instance to the above schema and do the validate instance, it gives this error-

> This is an invalid xsi:type 'urn:relationships_namespace:Customer'.

Second schema goes like this-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="urn:core_namespace" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:core_namespace" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:import namespace="urn:relationships_namespace" schemaLocation="UpdateCustomer2.xsd" />
  <xs:element name="record">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element xmlns:q1="urn:relationships_namespace" ref="q1:companyName" />
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="internalId" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Third-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="urn:relationships_namespace" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:relationships_namespace" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="companyName" type="xs:string" />
</xs:schema>
```

Would really appreciate if anyone can help get it validated in Visual Studio. I could use some piece of code for the same, but then my approach for the further process would totally change hence sticking to VS. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Posting the other two schemas would allow people to reproduce the error.

Comment: I have edited the question with those schemas.